# QGIS v.net not working for certain lines data

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I am trying to make a connected network using the v.net GRASS tool. It has worked for 3 vector line layers but is not working for two. I am not sure what the problem is. I used the same settings for other areas and it worked.

Here is the log:

```
QGIS version: 3.18.3-Zürich
QGIS code revision: 735cc85be9
Qt version: 5.14.2
GDAL version: 3.2.1
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
PDAL version: 2.2.0 (git-version: Release)
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.net' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-c' : False, '-s' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'arc_type' : [0,1], 'file' : '', 'input' : '/Users/m/Desktop/MilanQGIS/Roadsareaatest.shp', 'operation' : 1, 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'points' : '/Users/m/Desktop/MilanQGIS/GreenPointsAll.shp|layername=GreenPointsAll', 'threshold' : 200 }

g.proj -c wkt="/private/var/folders/zz/kzwtbnhn32jdwgqwbk4cb82h0000gn/T/processing_khAMMA/2be47da643f240ffba86fcfde72bf2cb/crs.prj"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="/Users/m/Desktop/MilanQGIS/Roadsareaatest.shp" output="vector_6139743fbe04f2" --overwrite -o
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="/Users/m/Desktop/MilanQGIS/GreenPointsAll.shp" layer="GreenPointsAll" output="vector_6139743fbe4723" --overwrite -o
g.region n=45.6686987 s=45.25495956129262 e=9.545194062986074 w=8.9114958
v.net input=vector_6139743fbe04f2 points=vector_6139743fbe4723 operation="connect" threshold=200 arc_type="line,boundary" output=output05daf869065f47c9bf4076b00c6207ca --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="line" input="output05daf869065f47c9bf4076b00c6207ca" output="/private/var/folders/zz/kzwtbnhn32jdwgqwbk4cb82h0000gn/T/processing_khAMMA/ed336cb5776743b4abf644b91934fd06/output.gpkg" format="GPKG" layer=1 --overwrite
Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.
Starting GRASS GIS...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing </private/var/folders/zz/kzwtbnhn32jdwgqwbk4cb82h0000gn/T/processing_khAMMA/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> ...
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <Roadsareaatest> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <Roadsareaatest>...
Importing 199222 features (OGR layer <Roadsareaatest>)...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <vector_6139743fbe04f2@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
10000..20000..30000..40000..50000..60000..70000..80000..90000..100000..110000..120000..130000..140000..150000..160000..170000..180000..190000..
WARNING: Updating spatial reference with embedded proj4 definition
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <GreenPointsAll> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <GreenPointsAll>...
Importing 9281 features (OGR layer <GreenPointsAll>)...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building topology for vector map <vector_6139743fbe4723@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Copying features...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Building topology for vector map <output05daf869065f47c9bf4076b00c6207ca@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
10000..20000..30000..40000..50000..60000..70000..80000..90000..100000..110000..120000..130000..140000..150000..160000..170000..180000..190000..
Copying attributes...
Building topology for vector map <output05daf869065f47c9bf4076b00c6207ca@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
10000..20000..30000..40000..50000..60000..70000..80000..90000..100000..110000..120000..130000..140000..150000..160000..170000..180000..190000..
v.net complete. 0 lines (network arcs) written to output.
Exporting 199338 features...
5..11..17..23..29..35..41..47..53..59..65..71..77..83..89..95..100
v.out.ogr complete. 199338 features (Line String type) written to <output05daf869065f47c9bf4076b00c6207ca> (GPKG format).
Execution of </private/var/folders/zz/kzwtbnhn32jdwgqwbk4cb82h0000gn/T/processing_khAMMA/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 210.39 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.net' finished
```